# Iphone video tag doesn't play after pressing done when video didn't finish loading

Tags: ios, iphone, html, html5-video

I'm using a video tag in my html in an iphone, and there is a bug that happens with the following sequence of steps:

1. The user clicks the "play" button
2. The quicktime player shows with the "loading" text
3. The user clicks the "done" button **while the player still says "loading"**
4. The html shows up again
5. The user clicks the "play" button again
6. Nothing happens (the quicktime player does not show)

I'm using a standard html5 video tag:

`<video type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'" poster="[postersrc]" src="[videosrc]" controls ></video>`

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

If the user waits untill the video is loaded and starts playing, this error does not happen (the user can play the video again).

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your code?